# Sign in with Facebook error with next-auth : self_signed_cert_in_chain

Tags: next.js, next-auth, facebook-authentication

I am following clone project youtube (https://youtu.be/g7nZ1R-5K40) and encountered problems applying facebook oauth.

My (1) codes (2) error message on the console (3) browser message are below.

Problem is, I made a consumer application for a Facebook developer but when I used it (its credential) with next-auth and tried sign-in, I get these errors.

URL is `localhost:3000`

How can I fix this?

(1) code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

(2) Console:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error self signed certificate in certificate chain {
  error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
  },
  providerId: 'facebook',
  message: 'self signed certificate in certificate chain'
}
```

(3) Browser:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you following any guidelines? If you share that link someone may help you.

Comment: Added guideline URL in the question body. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

for me worked set that env:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```